# How to create custom link with preg replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to create links with preg_replace that show link label with custom text.

Here example i want
**Input**

```
http://stackoverflow.com/ [click here]
```

**Output**

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">click here</a>
```

Here is code I'm trying and I got confused about how to use variable $1 and $2.

```
preg_replace(
"/(https?:\/\/[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]) \[((.*))\]/i",
"<a href=\"$1\">$2</a>",$text);
```

### updated

More condition is, If no `[click here]` occur at end of the string i want this `<a href="$1">$1</a>`.

Example
**Input**

```
http://stackoverflow.com/ [click here] bla bla bla
http://www.google.com/ bla bla bla
```

**Output**

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">click here</a> bla bla bla
<a href="http://www.google.com/">http://www.google.com/</a> bla bla bla
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for capturing and the [branch reset feature](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) to achieve desired result:

```
$pattern = '~(?=(https?://\S+))(?|\1 \[([^]]+)\]|(\1))~';
```

`(?|\1 \[([^]]+)\]|(\1))` Will capture to the 2nd capturing group the [`click here`] text if available, else paste the matched link from first capturing group.

```
$str = preg_replace($pattern, '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $str);
```

*Program output*:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">click here</a> bla bla bla
<a href="http://www.google.com/">http://www.google.com/</a> bla bla bla
```

[Test at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kU2qS6/2); [PHP test at eval.in](https://eval.in/238920);

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign return value of `preg_replace` back and you can simplify your regex:

```
$text = preg_replace('~(https?://\S+) +\[([^]]+)\]~i', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $text);
```

**Based on your edit you can do**:

```
$txt = 'http://stackoverflow.com/  bla bla bla';

$txt = preg_replace_callback('~(\bhttps?://\S+)(?:\s+\[([^]]+)\])?~i',
    function ($m) { $s='<a hr'.'ef="'.$m[1].'">';
         $s .= isset($m[2])? $m[2]:$m[1]; return $s.'</a>';}, $txt);

echo $txt;
//=> <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">http://stackoverflow.com/</a> bla bla bla
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
([^\[]*)\[(.*?)\]
```

substitute with :

```
<a href="$1">$2</a>
```

demo here : https://regex101.com/r/lU8eO2/1

in your code :

```
preg_replace('/([^\[]*)\[(.*?)\]/', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $text);
```

Comment: One more question, If no `[click here]` occur at end of string i want this `<a href="$1">$1</a>`.